# Postman: Could not convert YAML response to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api, yaml, postman

I have to test an API that returns a YAML response, but for the tests, I should find a string in the response.

For a JSON response I just have to do `JSON.parse(responseBody)`, but I can't do `YAML.parse(responseBody)`.

I searched for an add-on like `yamljs` but I didn't find anything...

Comment: Could you try to get the response as text and check the data that way, within the test? Use `pm.response.text()` to do this.

Comment: I didn't think to test it, it works ! Thanks a lot

Comment: I can add that as the answer and you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pm.response.text()` function to get the response `yml` data as text.

From here, you will be able to use that within a test to check for the pieces of data that you require.